# Trouble creating new nested resource with has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a nested resource with a has_one relationship.  When the form is submitted all the parameters look right, and it routes correctly to the `create` action.  However, something is making it error out inside the `create` action.

Error: `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass`

Relevant resources:

```
#models/employer.rb
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :employment_training_opportunity, dependent: :destroy
end

#models/employment_training_opportunity.rb
class EmploymentTrainingOpportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer
end
```

And the controller:

```
#controllers/employment_training_opportunities_controller.rb
class EmploymentTrainingOpportunitiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @employer = Employer.find(params[:employer_id])
    # error highlights line below
    @employment_training_opportunity = @employer.employment_training_opportunity.new(employment_training_opportunity_params)
    if @employment_training_opportunity.save
      redirect_to @employer, flash: {success: "Employment Opportunities was successfully created"}
    else
      render :new
    end
  end    
end
```

Some more clues I got:

When I put in a `binding.pry` I noticed that it is properly finding the `employer` resource, so `@employer` is returning an active record object.

When I call `@employer.employment_training_opportunity` it returns `nil`.  This makes sense because this employer resource does not yet have an associated `employment_training_opportunity` resource.

But when I call `@employer.employment_training_opportunity.new`, that is when it errors out with `NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass`.  I just don't get it because this works just fine with `has_many` associations for nested resources.

Comment: What is the value of `@employer`?

Comment: @Pavan it is an active record object, so it is not `nil`.

Comment: Can you confirm it is not nil?

Comment: Yes, with both `binding.pry` and bye bug.

Comment: I notice it does this: when I call `@employer.employment_training_opportunity` it returns `nil`.  Which is what I expect because this `employer` doesn't have an `employment_training_opportunity` yet.  but when I call `@employer.employment_training_opportunity.new` it errors out and says `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass`. Of course I don't mean to call new on `nil`, but for `has_many` nested resources it works just fine doing it that way.

Comment: Try changing  `@employment_training_opportunity = @employer.employment_training_opportunity.new(employment_training_opportunity_params)` to  `@employment_training_opportunity = @employer.build_employment_training_opportunity(employment_training_opportunity_params)`

Comment: now its saying this: `undefined method 'new' for #<EmploymentTrainingOpportunity:0x00...>`

Comment: Have you changed it correctly as per my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@employer.employment_training_opportunity` is nil, so you can't call new on it.  You could do this:

`@employer.employment_training_opportunity = EmploymentTrainingOpportunity.new(employment_training_opportunity_params)`

Which will create the new record and set up the relationship.  But this is cleaner, IMO:

`@employer.build_employment_training_opportunity(employment_training_opportunity_params)`